# Adding sources to a list variable in cmake vs. directly in add_executable

Tags: cmake

Why is it recommended to add sources to a list first, rather than directly to the executable?

```
PROJECT( helloworld )
SET( hello_SRCS hello.cpp )
ADD_EXECUTABLE( hello ${hello_SRCS} )
```

Why not just skip the `SET` line altogether?

Comment: `Why is it recommended...` - First time hear about such recommendation. Do whatever is more suitable for your concrete case. If you build executable from many sources and those sources require different preprocessing, it could be useful to have a variable which lists that sources. If you build simple executable from a few sources, direct `add_executable` would be right choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have seen this practice often enough to also think that it’s considered a good practice. For example, if you use the CLion IDE (which actually uses CMakeLists.txt as its project structure file), you’ll see that when you create a new project it creates a SOURCE_FILES variable by default.

One reason I can think of as to why this is a good practice is that if you want to build the same files into several targets. For example, you might want to have both static and shared binaries for your lib, so if you have a SOURCE_FILES var you just have to write something like:

```
add_library(myLibStatic STATIC ${SOURCE_FILES})
add_library(myLibShared SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})
```